# how to start valgrind to check one application with non-root account

Tags: valgrind, memcheck

how to start valgrind  to check one application with non-root account?

I have one application , it only start by these way:

```
su wrt-wxx --shell=/bin/bash -c " application  application  .cfg >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

I want to use valgrind to do memcheck.

```
 valgrind --log-file=./mem.log --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --trace-children=yes --undef-value-errors=no   su wrt-wxx --shell=/bin/bash -c " application  application  .cfg >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

It could not start the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to do it but have you tried to start valgrind (and not only your app) as wrt-wxx ?

```
su wrt-wxx --shell=/bin/bash -c "valgrind valgrind_options your_app >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```